# hints from verses that 6 days of creation is not literal

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, time, parashat-bereishit, creation, literalism

Are there hints in the verses of Genesis that the 6 "days" of creation are not literal, i.e. not 24 hour periods but rather some kind of "era".

Comment: http://www.geraldschroeder.com/AgeUniverse.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Genesis 1:14

> And God said, “Let there be lights in the vault of the sky to separate
>   the day from the night, and let them serve as signs to mark sacred
>   times, and days and years, **15**: and let them be lights in the vault of
>   the sky to give light on the earth.” And it was so. **16**: God made two
>   great lights—the greater light to govern the day and the lesser light
>   to govern the night. He also made the stars. **17**: God set them in the
>   vault of the sky to give light on the earth, **18**: to govern the day and
>   the night, and to separate light from darkness. And God saw that it
>   was good. **19**: And there was evening, and there was morning—the fourth
>   day.

How can there be three first "days", if the days (and the sun) were created only in the 4th day?

Comment: couldn't that refer to time? ie 24hrs of time?

Comment: I don't think hours existed back then... Hours are a concept that derives its meaning from the earth's rotation around the sun (/from the time of light and darkness on earth), so no sun (/no light)- no hours.

Comment: @OrenA Keep in mind that in halacha, an hour is rarely 60 minutes. It is merely a unit assigned to 1/12 of the time between sunrise and sunset. Re - no sun no hours, poses practical halachic questions even today in parts of the globe north or south of the "circles" during respective winters.

Comment: @ray You asked for hints not proofs.

Comment: @DanF nice point.

Comment: @ray That's why it's a hint not a proof.

Comment: Maybe , you forget the fact that in the first day god created light. Many rishonim say that it was created for this propouse , to turn it off/on and divide the days.

Comment: @DoubleAA right but this is totally ambiguous. could just as well say it refers to 24 hrs.

Comment: Well it COULD be 24 hours. It could be just as well 2 or 50 hours. I believe the reason you ask specifically about 24 hours is because you assume a "day" is literally a day, which is what you asked. My answer shows that it has nothing to do with today's common concept of a "day". Not proving it is, not proving it isn't, just showing the two are not related, which I think, show it isn't literal.

Answer (score 1):

Psalms 90:

> כִּי אֶלֶף שָׁנִים בְּעֵינֶיךָ כְּיוֹם אֶתְמוֹל כִּי יַעֲבֹר וְאַשְׁמוּרָה בַלָּיְלָה:
>
> For a thousand years are in Your eyes like yesterday, which passed, and a watch in the night

Of course this is not the pshat of bereshit, but , as you said , it is only a hint.

Comment: hint in parsha bereishis?

Comment: @ray are you sure there is one? You heard about it and forgot it?